# If statement with Two Variable

Tags: php

I have three variables as per the below:

```
$price              = floatval ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'property_price', true) );
$price_label        = esc_html ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'property_label', true) ); 
$price_label_before = esc_html ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'property_label_before', true) );
```

Where `$price` shows the price, `$price_label` is the label after the price and `$proce_label`_before is the label before the price.

I have the following code that works fine:

```
if ($price != 0) {
    $price = wpestate_show_price(get_the_ID(),$currency,$where_currency,1);  
} else {
    $price='<span class="price_label price_label_before">'.$price_label_before.'</span><span class="price_label ">'.$price_label.'</span>';
}
```

Which shows the price in a format like USD 20,000 per month when the `$price` field 20000, and $price_label is per month.

I want to change the code such that if `$price_label_before` has a value, the USD currency should be removed and replaced with what is in the  `$price_label_before` variable.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use short if for that:

```
(!empty($price_label_before) ? $price_label_before : 'USD')
```

Comment: Presumably `empty` should be superfluous and `$price_label_before ?: 'USD'` would do just fine too.

Comment: How do i change this is my formula?

Answer (score 0):

Hi managed to get it working with the following code:

```
if ($price != 0 && empty($price_label_before)) {
           $price = wpestate_show_price(get_the_ID(),$currency,$where_currency,1);  
       }else{
            $myprice = floatval   ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'property_price', true) );

           $price='<span class="price_label price_label_before">'.$price_label_before. '&nbsp;' .number_format($myprice).'</span><span class="price_label ">'.$price_label.'</span>';

       }
```